# Error while creating a new database: ORA-56752: Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) memory parameter invalid or not specified

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i'm trying to create a new database using "Database configuration assistant" from oracle 21c xe, but i'm getting the error during the creation process "ORA-56752: Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) memory parameter invalid or not specified"

I've already tried changing the automatic share memory value in the configuration options but the error remains the same. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked this already? https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/ora-56752-oracle-database-express-edition-xe-memory-paramet-6110

Comment: @FriendlyDragon the last comment in that post has the same error and unfortunately no one replied to him

Comment: What did you change the values to? Can you share the numbers or a screenshot? (Screenshots are usually discouraged on Stack Overflow, but since the DBCA GUI is a bit weird, a screenshot might help here.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using DBCA, it will default to 40% of your RAM, which means it might quite easily have picked some numbers larger than the 2G ceiling for XE.

Some safe ones to go with:

- sga_target = 1536
- pga_aggregate_target = 512.

which brings to you 2048. These are also the defaults for 23c XE/FREE so you'll be fine if you choose to upgrade later.